# Creating an autofilter search box

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a search box that filters the data based on a string inputted in a inputbox. Rather than filtering based on a single column I'd like to search the entire table (Currently A8:AK700 but may change in the future).

I have got a search function that works on a single column and filters the data accordingly, I then tried to create a loop to search one column after another, but this removes all data as I believe its looking for a match in all columns.

```
Sub Filter()
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

    Dim strName As String, LastColumn As Long, StartCell As Range, Si As Integer 'String Name
    Si = 1
    Set sht = Sheets("Contract History")
    Sheets("Contract History").Select
    Set StartCell = Range("A8")

    'Find Last Row and Column
    LastRow = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    LastColumn = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select
    'Search Function
    strName = InputBox("What would you like to search for?")

    Do
        Selection.AutoFilter Field:=Si, Criteria1:="=*" & strName & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
        Si = Si + 1
    Loop Until Si = 37
End Sub
```

As an example I'd like to search for Korea, and it show all rows of data containing Korea in either of the Customer, Location, or Source columns. Currently I get 0 results

Comment: You cannot filter across multiple columns like that. Once you filter on one column it excludes all results not in that filter. One method you can use is to employ a helper column at the end of your data set. In that column, you can test for the existence of the search term in all the columns for that row. Then you can filter on the rows where the term appears, using TRUE/FALSE or a numerical value or something. Alternatively, you can do it in code and mark that column based on a row search for the term.

Comment: Have you tried  with "Operator:=xlOr"?

Comment: @AlvaroCC xlOr didn't work

Comment: @MBSPG , sorry for missleading you ,  An alternative way of filtering data you may find useful is by using sql as described here https://analystcave.com/excel-using-sql-in-vba-on-excel-data/

Comment: You need to ask yourself, how would I do this manually? VBA is great at automating existing process - but it can't change how existing functionality works. You'll need to come up with a process that you can perform manually ( @ScottHoltzman response is ideal ) and then look to code it.